# Time spent on tasks in next report

Tags: taskwarrior

I'm new to taskwarrior and I've set up my task list and it show appropriately in my `next` report.

I was now trying to implement a way to show in my reports the time I've spent in tasks that show in my `next`report. I've check [similar threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/taskwarrior) but the comments weren't satisfactory.

The naive way to do this would be to start a task with the `start` command. The problem is that the active report variable is not cumulative between issuing `start`and `stop`. On top of this the `ACTIVE` tag makes it more important just because it was started.

In my user case, I usually want to split my time among certain urgent tasks so I would like to know how much time I spend on each individual task.

Any suggestions?

I tried some [tools](https://taskwarrior.org/tools/) that show in taskwarrior's webpage. For example: [this](https://github.com/gkssjovi/trackwarrior) and [this](https://github.com/kostajh/taskwarrior-time-tracking-hook) but I couldn't make them work.